# INSERT with PDO. Should I use try...catch?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just started using PDO and I have this code to insert values in my table.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$sql = "INSERT INTO lists (ID, Title, Timestamp, Plays, Likes) 
VALUES (:ID, :Title, :Timestamp, :Plays, :Likes)";
$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':ID'=>$list[$i]["id"],
              ':Title'=>$list[$i]["title"],
              ':Timestamp'=>$list[$i]["timestamp"],
              ':Plays'=>$list[$i]["playcount"],
              ':Likes'=>$list[$i]["likes"]));
```

From reading over the forums, I understand that sometimes I would need to use the try...catch for safety reasons.I am really confused...In my case, should I change anything in order to use try...catch???

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "for safety reasons" --- for "safety" from what?

Comment: I thought it was for error handling? Because I read "If your app doesnt catch the exception thrown from the PDO constructor, the default action taken is to terminate the script and display a back trace. This back trace will likely reveal the full database connection details."

Comment: we have no idea on how your app is built. You might have a global try-catch that would handle all the exceptions. And it might be a solution in case if you're fine with it

Comment: @CharleyB0y Or you could just be fine having the app terminate with uncaught exceptions for queries. But you will definitely need to catch the PDO constructor somehow.

Comment: So then is it enough to simply use: http://pastebin.com/p6TnMxKA

Comment: @CharleyB0y typically your queries would be separate from the constructor since you will have other code in there. Wrapping hundreds of lines in a try/catch block is probably not very good practice. For that, see zerkms' recommendation for a global exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the delete, accidentally hit post before it was complete.  Here is one way to implement error reporting when using PDO:

```
try {
if($dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password)) {
// Set Errorhandling to Exception instead of PDO error reporting
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} else {
  throw new Exception(": Connection Error ");
}
...later in code block
$sql = "INSERT INTO lists (ID, Title, Timestamp, Plays, Likes) 
VALUES (:ID, :Title, :Timestamp, :Plays, :Likes)";

if($q = $dbh->prepare($sql)) {
$q->execute(array(':ID'=>$list[$i]["id"],
          ':Title'=>$list[$i]["title"],
          ':Timestamp'=>$list[$i]["timestamp"],
          ':Plays'=>$list[$i]["playcount"],
          ':Likes'=>$list[$i]["likes"]));
}else {
 throw new Exception(“: Error on Insert “);
}
//now catch all throw errors
} catch(Exception $e){
$mes = $date.": bdh errors ";
$mes .= $e->getMessage();
//send errors to system error reporting
error_log($mes);
}
```

Have a look at [PDO Exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) for more info on the PDO Error driver

Comment: `if($q = $dbh->prepare($sql))` --- what's this for?

Comment: I think OP is using "$q" instead of "$stmt = $bdh->prepare($sql)" which is what you would typically see.  Also, if prepare fails (missing values in post etc) then an error is thrown.